# CSS - Making a repeating background image stretch to browser window size

Tags: css, image, window, wrapper, stretch

This is a problem with a theme that I bought, and I have already tried to contact the owner (with no luck).

It should be a fairly easy fix, it's just that I can't work out how to do it! (I have done my research).

You can view the theme here: http://igeekify.com/_templates/liftoff/www/

To re-create the problem, just drag the window size so that it is smaller in width than the content, then scroll to the right. You will notice the header background doesn't stretch all the way.

The background image is for the DIV '#frame-header', which has the class '.wrapper'. I believe that the problem has something to do with the width of '.wrapper' which is defined.

Any help is really appreciated!

Comment: Does anybody actually ever make their window smaller than `940px` then scroll right?

Comment: I use Cinch on the Mac, an app similar to the resizing Windows 7 where you can drag windows to the left or right so that you can view two at the same time. If I was to do this, then the page is broken. So yes, people that use Windows 7 or Cinch do!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you might need to add a min-width property to the 'frame-header' div:

```
<style type="text/css">
#frame-header
{
    min-width: 940px;
}
</style>
```

Comment: Spot on! I'll have to look into this, never had to set a minimum width before. Thanks so much for such a quick response!

Comment: Great. If you try in old IE and min-width doesn't work, try width: 100%;

Answer (score 0):

Try using the following code:

```
image width:100%;
```

Comment: @terry Jan Reedy m sorry for that coz I am new here and learning how to post